# How to click on a button(no Id in tag) in html page after 5 seconds when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, tags

A boog noob Alert!...I've html `div` like this

```
<div class="col mt-2">
<button @click="selected = Array.from(header); render()" class="btn btn-light-alt btn-sm">Select all</button>
<button @click="selected = []" class="btn btn-light-alt btn-sm">Clear selection</button></div>
```

All I want to do is click on this `Select all` button after 5 seconds webpage is loaded. I've searched for this way to do it & I found this

```
setTimeout(document.getElementByID('button').click(),5000);
```

I think `button` is Id here???...But there is no Id in my html tag...we can see only class is available...so can I achieve this requirement?...Any similar threads that you guys know?

Comment: You are *calling* the click function, instead of just *passing* it as param. remove the `()`

Comment: `setTimeout(document.querySelector('.col.mt-2 > .btn').click, 5000)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the HTML, and that button's function is always the same, then you don't actually need to trigger the click. Just run the functions.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   selected = Array.from(header);
   render();
},5000);
```